# Store an Array in sessionstorageItem

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript objects. I would like to store the following array on `sessionstorageItem`, but it was giving me error. How can I able to store an array in `sessionstorageItem`?

```
data=[];
data[0] = [{
    "num": 29,
    "ser": 1,
}, {
    "num": 44,
    "ser": 2,
}] 
data[1]=[{
    "num": 10,
    "ser": 3,
}]

 allData = data.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b) });
  // the following line gives me an error
 var MDData=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.MDData);
 if (MDData!==null) {console.log("Hello")}
 sessionStorage.setItem('MyData', JSON.stringify(allData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webStorage` can only store `strings`. So you need to stringify your data.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('Myata', JSON.stringify(allData));
```

To retrieve it back you can do:

```
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.Myata);
```

Comment: How could I retrieve back after I store it?

Comment: @mystackoverflow. I updated

Comment: Once SOF allows me, then I will mark as answer

Comment: I have marked as an answer. However, if you check my question, which I have updated, it gives me an error. Do u have any idea?

Comment: @mystackoverflow From where are you getting MData? Whats its contents? And what error do you get?

Comment: Also a note here, sessionStorage or localStorage can only store 5mb at a time, use cookies if you're storing more than that

Answer (score 0):

you have and extra ')' in "sessionStorage.setItem('Myata', sell.allData));"